# Ширина div по контенту

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте, уважаемые знатоки верстки! Подскажите плиз кроссбраузерное решение задания ширины div по содержимому дочерних элементов. Т.е. имеется, например

```
<div id="l0_b1" style="display: block">
    <span id="l1_s1">тут контент с неизвестной шириной</span>
</div>
```

Как установить ширину `l0_b1` == ширине `l1_s1`?

ПС. Очень желательно без js-хаков.

Comment: @Invis1ble2, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 13):

Как уже было сказано либо inline-block либо inline, если div-ву нужны блочные свойства,то `display: inline-block;`, но в этом случае необходимо задавать еще `vertical-align: top;` что-бы блок не съезжал вниз при добавлении контента.
А вообще сами можете потренироваться, почти в каждом браузере есть отладчик для разработчиков, в FireFox пишите атрибут и по очереди прокликиваете все значения, этот вариант просто незаменим для новичков, можно наглядно всё увидеть, как элементы ведут себя.

Comment: спасибо за советы, буду пробовать
дело в том, что я действительно новичек в верстке

Answer (score 9):

Эту задачу можно решить несколькими способами:

**1** - С помощью `display: inline-block;`:

```css
#l0_b1 {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid purple;
}
```

```html
<div id="l0_b1">
  <span id="l1_s1">тут контент с неизвестной шириной</span>
</div>
```

---

**2** - С помощью `display: block;`:

```css
#l0_b1 {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid purple;
}
```

```html
<div id="l0_b1">
  <span id="l1_s1">тут контент с неизвестной шириной</span>
</div>
```

*Используя `float`, не забывайте про `clear: both`*

---

**3** - С помощью `display: inline-flex;`:

```css
#l0_b1 {
  display: inline-flex;
  border: 1px solid purple;
}
```

```html
<div id="l0_b1">
  <span id="l1_s1">тут контент с неизвестной шириной</span>
</div>
```

---

**4** - С помощью `display: table;`:

```css
#l0_b1 {
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid purple;
}
```

```html
<div id="l0_b1">
  <span id="l1_s1">тут контент с неизвестной шириной</span>
</div>
```

---

И блоки, и флексы, и таблицы могут оборачивать блок по его ширине. В зависимости от вашей общей задачи, вы можете выбрать самый подходящий вам вариант.

Comment: Не думал, что когда-то мне это пригодится
Впрочем благодарен)

Answer (score 4):

```
width: fit-content;
```

Правда с поддержкой там пока не очень все радостно.

Comment: Это свойство НЕ поддерживается только IE и Edge. Остальные браузеры адекватно воспринимают. Кстати спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой способ задать диву float:left/right (если это допустимо для позиционирования) или display:inline, тогда его размер будет полностью зависеть от содержимого. (Добавьте больше информации, что должно получаться)

Comment: display: inline не подходит, а вот float: left - вроде оно.
возможно ли теперь отцентровать блок по горизонтали?

Comment: Старенький хак:  
<center><div>text</div></center>

Comment: Почитайте http://www.xiper.net/collect/html-and-css-tricks/pozitsionirovanie/inline-block.html может поможет.

Comment: Не думаю что это правильно решение, потому как выравнивание не всегда удобно. <img src="/vote/19946/up/" width="1px"/>

Answer (score 1):

Клевое решение `float`. Выровнять

```
clear:both;
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо за "Clear:both;"!